# I have the next integral and I'm integrating it by parts on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have the following integral
$$ \int _c Re(z) + (1-z)e^z dz $$

where C is the unit circle

So I've separated it in two integrals and if I parametrize the first one, it gives me 0. For the second one I've used integration by parts:

$$\int_c(1-z)e^zdz=(1-z)e^z|_c+\int_ce^zdz$$

I could say maybe that

$$\int_ce^zdz=e^z|_c$$

but what do i do next? How do i find the value of the integrals?

Comment: $\int_0^1 e^{\gamma(t)} \gamma'(t) dt = e^{\gamma(1)} -e^{\gamma(0)} = 0$

Comment: and for $(1-z)e^z|_c$?

Comment: You need to do a little work! What exactly are you asking?

Comment: how do i find the end points of intregration. Like if i had a real integral i would have $(1-z)e^z|_0 ^1$ . Maybe a parametrization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_C f' dz &=& \int_0^1 f'(C(t)) C'(t)dt \\
&=&  \int_0^1 (f\circ C)'(t)dt \\
&=&  (f\circ C) \mid_0^1 \\
&=&  f(C(1))-f(C(0))
\end{eqnarray}
Hence if $C(0) = C(1)$ then $\int_C f' dz = 0$.

The integration by parts formula is the similar to the usual integration rule:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_C (f \cdot g)' dz &=& \int_0^1 (f \cdot g)'(C(t)) C'(t)dt \\
&=&  \int_0^1 ((f \cdot g)\circ C)'(t)dt \\
&=&  ((f \cdot g)\circ C) \mid_0^1 \\
&=&  f(C(1))g(C(1))-f(C(0))g(C(0)) \\
&=& \int_0^1 (f' \cdot g+ f \cdot g')(C(t)) C'(t)dt \\
&=& \int_0^1 (f' \cdot g)(C(t)) C'(t)dt + \int_0^1 (f \cdot g')(C(t)) C'(t)dt \\
&=& \int_C f' \cdot g dz + \int_C f \cdot g'dz
\end{eqnarray}

Hence $\int_C f' \cdot g dz = f(C(1))g(C(1))-f(C(0))g(C(0)) - \int_C f \cdot g'dz$.

Now let $f'(z) = e^z$, $g(z) = 1-z$ and note that $C(0) =C(1)$. Then
$\int_C f' \cdot g dz = -\int_C f \cdot g' dz = \int_C e^z dz = e^{C(1)}-e^{C(0)} = 0$.

Comment: C(0) = C(1) is given by the formula?  And this would work for any kind of valid domain?

Comment: Presumably the circle starts and ends at the same point. I don't know what you are asking in your second question.

Comment: The formula for partial derivation

Comment: If f,g are analytic on the path then yes